# ORDER BY year and date in mysql and gridview

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

im having salary table,in which im storing salary details with corresponding month and year and payment date.Im displaying these data in gridview in my ASP.net c# application. i want to display the data like latest in first page.
Below my sample salary database:

```
+------------+-------+----------+------+----------+------+-------------+
| EmployeeID | Gross | TotalDed | Net  |  Month   | Year | paymentdate |
+------------+-------+----------+------+----------+------+-------------+
|       2066 |  2219 |     3750 | 1531 | January  | 2016 | 30.01.2016  |
|       2023 |  2218 |     1649 |  570 | January  | 2016 | 30.01.2016  |
|       2001 |  2219 |     3750 | 1531 | October  | 2015 | 30.10.2015  |
|       2023 |  2218 |     1649 |  570 | October  | 2015 | 30.10.2015  |
|       2034 |  2328 |     5728 | 3400 | October  | 2015 | 30.10.2015  |
|       2023 |  2218 |     1649 |  570 | November | 2015 | 30.11.2015  |
|       2030 |  2219 |     1550 |  669 | November | 2015 | 30.11.2015  |
|       2047 |  2218 |     1649 |  570 | November | 2015 | 30.11.2015  |
|       2031 |  2219 |     8450 | 6231 | December | 2015 | 30.12.2015  |
|       2057 |  2219 |     8450 | 6231 | December | 2015 | 30.12.2015  |
|       2023 |  2218 |     1649 |  570 | December | 2015 | 30.12.2015  |
+------------+-------+----------+------+----------+------+-------------+
```

i want this table to display in gridview with pagination.

```
 String sQuery = @"SELECT EmployeeID,GrossSalary,TotalDed,NetSalary,Month,Year,paymentdate
                                    FROM  salary ";

                MySqlDataAdapter ada = new MySqlDataAdapter(sQuery, GlobalCS.objMyCon);                          

                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    ada.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
```

But it displays latest to last page. 
if i use

`SELECT EmployeeID,GrossSalary,TotalDed,NetSalary,Month,Year,paymentdate FROM  salary order by Paymentdate`

then it displays Jan2016,oct 2016,nov 2016,dec 2016.
But what i want to display as jan2016,dec 2015, nov 2015, oct 2015
I tried

```
SELECT EmployeeID,GrossSalary,TotalDed,NetSalary,Month,Year,paymentdate FROM  salary order by month and year
```

the output is mixing of all data. So how can i get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Paymentdate` is `string` datatype then `order by Paymentdate` order your results in `Lexicographical order`.

Before order convert `Paymentdate` to `date`.

```
SELECT 
  `EmployeeID`,
  `GrossSalary`,
  `TotalDed`,
  `NetSalary`,
  `Month`,
  `Year`,
  `paymentdate` 
FROM  salary 
order by STR_TO_DATE(`paymentdate`,'%d.%m.%Y') DESC
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97ab5/7)

**Note** :- Its a bad practice to store the `date` data in `string` datatype instead of `date` datatype